# Adapter to change text in fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter, fragmentmanager

I have been trying all day to set a text to textviews from a fragment. I tried doing it without an adapter but now I am trying it with an adapter. At this moment it crashes and gives me a NullPointerException on the following line  `FragmentManager fm = ((NieuwToevoegen)context).getFragmentManager();`, but I am pretty sure that won't be the only problem. In my app I want to place different frameLayouts according to your input. And according to the amount of frameLayouts, I got different strings for the textviews. It is the first time I am ever working with fragments.

If someone knows a better way to do this, please tell me.

My activity

```
public class NieuwToevoegen extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button buttonVerstuur;
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nieuw_toevoegen);
        buttonVerstuur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVerstuur);

        buttonVerstuur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView aantalTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAantal);
                aantalTxt.setEnabled(false);
                int aantal = Integer.parseInt(aantalTxt.getText() + "");
                Log.d("onclickButtonVerstuur", aantal + "");
               tekstFragmentAdapter adapter = new tekstFragmentAdapter(NieuwToevoegen.this,aantal);

            }});}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                goBack();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void goBack(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent i = new Intent(NieuwToevoegen.this, startScherm.class);
        Log.d("backbutton", i + "");
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        goBack();
    }

    public void addFragment(int id) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(id, new fragmentItem());
        Log.d("addfragment", ft+"");
        ft.commit();
    }
```

My adapter

```
public class tekstFragmentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<tekstFragment> {
    private Context context;
    private Integer aantal;

        public tekstFragmentAdapter(Context context, int aantalFr) {
            super(context, 0, aantalFr);
            aantal=aantalFr;
        }
        FragmentManager fm = ((NieuwToevoegen)context).getFragmentManager();
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_layout, parent, false);
            }

            TextView tekst1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tekst2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView tekst3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            switch(aantal) {
                case 1:
                    tekst1.setText("@string/een_item1_string");
                    addFragment(R.id.frameLayout1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tekst1.setText("@string/twee_item1_string");
                    tekst2.setText("@string/twee_item2_string");
                    addFragment(R.id.frameLayout1);
                    addFragment(R.id.frameLayout2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tekst1.setText("@string/drie_item1_string");
                    tekst2.setText("@string/drie_item2_string");
                    tekst3.setText("@string/drie_item3_string");
                    addFragment(R.id.frameLayout1);
                    addFragment(R.id.frameLayout2);
                    addFragment(R.id.frameLayout3);
                    break;
                default:
                    TextView aantalIngevuld = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAantal);
                    aantalIngevuld.setEnabled(true);

                    break;}

            return convertView;
        }
    public void addFragment(int id) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(id, new fragmentItem());
        Log.d("addfragment", ft + "");
        ft.commit();
    }
    }
```

Fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/gallery_icon"
        android:background="#00000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery_icon"
            android:background="#00000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout3">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery_icon"
            android:background="#00000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

tekstFragment only contains the following

```
public class tekstFragment {
    private String tekst;

    public tekstFragment( String tekst) {
        this.tekst = tekst;
    }


    public String getTekst() {
        return tekst;
    }
}
```

The strings I am trying to add

```
<string name="drie_item1_string">Voeg een foto toe van een pull/sweater/jas</string>
<string name="drie_item2_string">Voeg een foto toe van een t-shirt/top</string>
<string name="drie_item3_string">Voeg een foto toe van een rok/short/broek</string>
<string name="twee_item1_string">Voeg een foto toe van een pull/sweater/jas</string>
<string name="twee_item2_string">Voeg een foto toe van een kleedje/broekpak/playsuit</string>
<string name="een_item1_string">Voeg een foto toe van een kleedje/broekpak/playsuit</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to correct the null pointer exception problem

```
public class tekstFragmentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<tekstFragment> {
    private Context context;
    private Integer aantal;
    FragmentManager fm;
        public tekstFragmentAdapter(Context context, int aantalFr) {
            super(context, 0, aantalFr);
            aantal=aantalFr;
            this.context= context
            fm = ((NieuwToevoegen)context).getFragmentManager();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_layout, parent, false);
            }

            TextView tekst1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tekst2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            TextView tekst3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            switch(aantal) {
                case 1:
                    tekst1.setText("@string/een_item1_string");
                    addFragment(R.id.frameLayout1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tekst1.setText("@string/twee_item1_string");
                    tekst2.setText("@string/twee_item2_string");
                    addFragment(R.id.frameLayout1);
                    addFragment(R.id.frameLayout2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tekst1.setText("@string/drie_item1_string");
                    tekst2.setText("@string/drie_item2_string");
                    tekst3.setText("@string/drie_item3_string");
                    addFragment(R.id.frameLayout1);
                    addFragment(R.id.frameLayout2);
                    addFragment(R.id.frameLayout3);
                    break;
                default:
                    TextView aantalIngevuld = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAantal);
                    aantalIngevuld.setEnabled(true);

                    break;}

            return convertView;
        }
    public void addFragment(int id) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(id, new fragmentItem());
        Log.d("addfragment", ft + "");
        ft.commit();
    }
    }
```

but why are you casting your context with your Activtiy **NieuwToevoegen**, just put the context as parameter to your adapter

Comment: please try this to remove the null pointer exception and if you have other problems leave a comment, Good luck

Comment: it did fix the null pointer exception, but it is not doing anything right now. It doesn't get to my switch.I thought I had to cast it because I am writing it in my adapter instead of my activity NieuwToevoegen? 

I am just new to android and it is not going that wel so far.

Comment: could explain what are trying to achieve, this is what i understand for so far : user put text (Right ?)in your app and click on a button, and according to what he put you display a text and multiple fragment(why add multiple fragment ?), please edit your answer with more explanation and i will try to help you to achieve what you want to do, bests

Comment: I wil add the strings.I have a field where the user can put in a number from 1-3, when they put in 1 I want to make 1 frameLayout visible where I have an ImageButton. Next to the image button will be some text. My app is to save outfits, so when you choose 1 you can only add a dress and when you select 2 you can choose a top and jeans. So I have different strings in my xml which explain what you can add. Eventually you need to put pictures in it but that is the next step.

Answer (score 1):

i preferred to post another answer because it not gonna be related to the first one, i will put a structure code and will continue depending on your needs :

```
package my.game.androidstarter;
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class NieuwToevoegen extends Activity {

    Button buttonVerstuur;
    EditText editTextInput; // so user could insert a text from 1 to 3 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nieuw_toevoegen);
        buttonVerstuur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVerstuur);
        editTextInput  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText); // add your edit text in your xml layout "nieuw_toevoegen"
        editTextInput.setEnabled(false);

        buttonVerstuur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int aantal = Integer.parseInt(editTextInput.getText().toString()); // get the number input inserted by user
                Log.d("onclickButtonVerstuur", aantal + "");
                callFragment(aantal);

            }});}

    private void callFragment(int aantal) {

            switch (aantal) {
            case 1:
                YourCustomFragment1 fragment = new YourCustomFragment1(); // if 1 --> your custom fragment one

                break;
            case 2:
                YourCustomFragment2 fragment = new YourCustomFragment2(); // if 2 --> your custom fragment two

                break;
            case 3:
                YourCustomFragment3 fragment = new YourCustomFragment3(); // if 2 --> your custom fragment three

                break;
            default:
                // TODO if user insert a number that is not 1 or 2 or 3 (and he can do thant)
                break;

            }

            // charge the fragment that was created depending on  input number
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit(); // You should have frame_container (frame layout) defined in your nieuw_toevoegen.xml
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                goBack();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void goBack(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent i = new Intent(NieuwToevoegen.this, startScherm.class);
        Log.d("backbutton", i + "");
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        goBack();
    }
```

now all you have to do is to create three different cutom fragments (class that extends **`Fragment`**) and then customize each fragments differently with layout, views, button, image ....

hope this was clear enough !

Comment: I didn't think of making 3 fragments, thank you. I will try it out and answer you back later.

Comment: It works now thank you. But for some weird reason my titlebar is gone so I can't click on the back icon. For the rest it works fine.

Comment: good for you Naomi, the status bar gone in the fragment i assume, nothing weird just go inside the xml of the activity and check if the fragment_layour( the content of the fragment) doesn't hide the status bar, if you have trouble fix it just put the xml file ;), good luck for your study